# How can you reference path to resources in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I am trying to load series of pictures to create animation in Android Studio. I managed to spot similar thread and i got to this stage:

```
fun loadPics(context: Context, path: String, iconList: MutableList<Bitmap>): MutableList<Bitmap>{
    val assetManager = context.assets
    try
    {
        var `is`: InputStream
        var files = assetManager.list(path)
        for(i in files!!.indices) {
            `is` = assetManager.open(path + files[i])
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(`is`)
            iconList.add(i, bitmap)
        }
    }
    catch (e: IOException)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    finally {
        return iconList
    }
}
```

My really basic question is how do I reference path? i tried right - clicking on resource and copying path / reference but assetManager always returns nothing..

Tried copying paths by righ clicking resource files
res/drawable/
res/
absolute path C:\Users..\AndroidStudioProjects\ImageViewer\app\src\main\res\drawable\

Comment: You cannot get resources via a path on Android. You must retrieve them through `context.resources`.

Comment: I dont mind to get it this way like you are suggesting -> context.resources.assets.list(pathArg) but question is how to define pathArg taken by list function

Comment: See what it says in the entry for `/raw` in the table on this page of the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but this is exact apporach I am trying at the moment ->when I use : pictList.add(0, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.filename)) everything seems ok so why when using this :
        inpStr = assetManager.open("drawable/filename.png") I am getting IO exception file not found

Comment: I just noticed I can even see preview of picture when I hover over argument in android studio, but it still throws exception when run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only resources you can open as an InputStream are **raw** resources and **assets**. It won't work for resources in other directories like `res/drawable`.

You can put files in `res/raw` and then access them as an InputStream via `context.resources.openRawResource()` using their `R.raw` ID. The advantage with raw resources is that they can be organized by device and locale characteristics just like layout and string resources, so the system takes care of selecting the appropariate flavor of the file. e.g. you could have a `res/raw/myFile.txt` and `res/raw-large/myFile.txt` and it will give you the specialized file on large screen devices. Also, if you bundle your app for Google Play, the store can tailor the download for the device so raw files that will never be used on a specific device won't be included.

You can put files in `src/main/assets` (you might have to create this directory) and access them as an InputStream via `context.resources.assets.open()`. The advantage with assets is that you can organize them with subdirectories inside `src/main/assets`. You can list asset files using `context.resources.assets.list()`.

---

#### Assets Example:

You have an image here: `src/main/assets/picture.png`.

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun Context.loadBitmapAsset(fileNameInAssets: String): Bitmap {
    val stream = assets.open(fileNameInAssets)
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)
}
```

If you call `loadBitmapAsset("picture.png")` it will load your `picture.png`.

Or if you want to open all files in `res/main/assets` as images:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun Context.loadAllAssetsAsBitmaps(): List<Bitmap> {
    return assets.list("") // we use empty string for the root directory in assets
        .map { BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assets.open(it)) }
}
```

---

#### Raw resource example:

You have an image here: `src/main/res/raw/picture.png`

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun Context.loadRawBitmap(@RawRes resId: Int): Bitmap {
    val stream = resources.openRawResource(resId)
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)
}
```

If you call `loadBitmapAsset(R.raw.picture)` it will load your `picture.png`.

Or if you want to open all files in `res/main/res/raw` as images:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun Context.loadAllRawResourcesAsBitmaps(): List<Bitmap> {
    val rawIds = R.raw::class.java.fields.map { it.int }
    return rawIds.map { BitmapFactory.decodeStream(resources.openRawResource(it)) }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but context.resources.openRawResource() does not work for me as it requires defined id and context.resources.assets.open() throws same exception when called (with string argument) regardless of in which folder my files are. Is there any way to open picture with method that takes path in form of String ? That would be what I really need

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thank you!!!! my mistake was referencing path + filename instead filename alone